# Sidekiq not updating email template devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sidekiq

I am having a rails application which uses sidekiq for sending asynchronous devise email. But in production environment, for confirmation email server is using confirmation instructions from devise gem and not from my views. Please help

Comment: Did you generate the devise views and change them to your liking?

Comment: I am using devise scope_views true. So I am having users/mailer . Ideally it should work. It is working in development environment but not in production